# Saving page contents using Requests in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been trying to access the .txt files off a website using the Requests module. When I log in using the username and password manually I'm able to see the true data in my browser.

```
Point Code  Issue Date  Trade Date  Region  Pricing Point   Low High    Average Volume  Deals   Delivery Start Date Delivery End Date
RMTNWW  2018-10-09  2018-10-08  Rocky Mountains Northwest Wyoming Pool  2.910   2.955   2.935   323 44  2018-10-09  2018-10-09
RMTOPAL 2018-10-09  2018-10-08  Rocky Mountains Opal    2.925   3.050   2.965   209 40  2018-10-09  2018-10-09
```

But when I try accessing the same page with my script and print the content with

```
print(page.content)
```

The output comes out as the html source:

```
   b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n\n<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>\n<meta name="csrf-token" content="s35g4TAUN6+5V8Xi8x7u6f2FwziX3gbW9iY9D45HnEw="/>\n<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
\n<meta name="description" content="Natural Gas Intelligence">\n<meta name="keywords" content="gas, natural gas, natural gas prices, enery prices, NYMEX, nymex settlement, aga, storage, natural gas data, henry hub, ferc, power, electricity, electric, megawatt, methane, reliability, inside, ngi">\n\n\n\n<meta content="false" name="has-log-view" />\n<!--<meta content="IE=EmulateIE7" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
    .
    .
    .
```

Nothing inside this HTML has any of the tags shown above (Point Code, Issue Date, etc...) so I feel this might be a log in problem. The sign on URL is `https://www.naturalgasintel.com/user/login` whereas the file is located in a path `https://www.naturalgasintel.com/ext/resources/Data-Feed/Daily-GPI/2018/10/20181009td.txt`.

My script is:

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
    data_url = 'https://naturalgasintel.com/ext/resources/Data-Feed/Daily-GPI/'
    username = ''
    password = ''
    login_data = dict(username=username, password=password)
    c.post(data_url, data=login_data, headers={'Referer':'https://www.naturalgasintel.com/'})
    page = c.get('https://www.naturalgasintel.com/ext/resources/Data-Feed/Daily-GPI/2018/10/20181009td.txt', stream=True)
    print(page.content)
```

I'd like to save the actual .txt contents of the page and not the html source using the `open` function where I can `write` the contents into a file using something like:

```
localfile = 'output_{}.csv'
datafile = open(localfile, "w", encoding="utf-8")
datafile.write(page)
datafile.close()
```

How can I get these contents instead of the html source?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16694907/how-to-download-large-file-in-python-with-requests-py

Comment: I've tried this method as well and it still outputs the same HTML source code as local_filename when called to the url. Could it be the log in that is the problem?

Comment: You must first login, and than you can use returned cookies to get another content. You cannot expect to be auto logged in.

Comment: How would I implement cookies to work down the line? Would I first write something like  `req1 = requests.post(url)` then `req2 = requests.post(data_url, cookies=req1.cookies)` ? First being `url = 'https://www.naturalgasintel.com/user/login'` and `data_url = 'https://www.naturalgasintel.com/ext/resources/Data-Feed/Daily-GPI/2018/10/20181009td.txt' ?`

Comment: First check whether you login successfully. Second, you set `stream=True` so you have to do as Chris said.